# Why is Angular2 adding random generated attributes to html elements after render

Tags: html, dom, angular

I am having hard time understanding why is Angular2 adding these weird attributes to HTML elements after app is loaded (ex. on provided screenshot"_ngcontent-cxi-6"). I provided screenshot from DevTools with example.

Screenshot from DevTools.
[image]

That attribute always has fixed prefix "_ngcontent-". The rest is generated randomly but is consistent on every HTML element.

The problem comes when i want to insert HTML that i generate in Component or retrieve from Server with directive [innerHtml]. In that case elements in inserted HTML code do not get Angular's attribute:

```
 <span [innerHtml]="'<span>some text </span>'"></span>
```

Result of [innerHtml] binding is on picture below:

[image]

**CSS styling problem**

When i want to style these printed elements, with injected css file, nothing happens. 
CSS file is inserted with "styleUrls" property of @Component:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'someHtmlTemplate.html',
    styleUrls: ['someCSSfile.css'],
})
```

Style that gets injected into HTML is formatted into this:

```
span[_ngcontent-cxi-6] {
   background: pink;
   font-size: 20px; 
}
```

In this case CSS is looking for *span* with attribute [_ngcontent-cxi-6], thus making it unable to style it.

**Possible solution**
This CSS code solves things

```
:host >>> h3 { color: red; }
```

is compiled after injection into HTML:

```
[_nghost-krr-4] > > > span {
   background: pink;
   font-size: 20px;
}
```

But it is a crazy workaround solution for something so simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, it depends on the encapsulation mode you use on your component for shadow DOM. By default, it's the emulated mode so Angular2 adds things on elements for this.

- `ViewEncapsulation.None` - No Shadow DOM at all. Therefore, also no style encapsulation.
- `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` - No Shadow DOM but style encapsulation emulation.
- `ViewEncapsulation.Native` - Native Shadow DOM.